# SKAction Completion Handlers; usage in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, handler, skaction, completion

I'm new to Swift and SpriteKit. A lot of the samples of SpriteKit Actions are in Objective C, which I can't map to, nor get working, in Swift.

If running an SKAction, and upon SKAction completion wanting to do something else, how do I get this right, in Swift?

```
    spaceMan.runAction(spaceManDeathAnimation, completion: {
        println("red box has faded out")
    })
```

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

```
for i in 0...29 {
    textures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "spaceManDeath_\(i)"))
}
spaceManDeathAnimation = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(textures, timePerFrame: 0.15625))
```

Comment: What you want is a SKAction running a block in a SKAction sequence.

Comment: what do the spaceManDeathAnimation action does ? how it is defined? can you share the code for it as well?

Comment: Search the page for "completion" to get some good examples. http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/07/02/Game-development-tutorial-Swift-and-SpriteKit-Part-4-Actions.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You completion code is not called since your "death" action is running forever, which means it will never end.

You can use

```
+ repeatAction:count:
```

method for setting a count for how many repeats will be made before finishing:

```
spaceManDeathAnimation = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(textures, timePerFrame: 0.15625), count:5)
```

Answer (score 6):

Found an issue here:

```
spaceManDeathAnimation = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(textures, timePerFrame: 0.15625), count: 1)
```

Also,as sangony posted a very nice link - solved the completion block syntax to

```
    spaceMan.runAction(spaceManDeathAnimation, completion: {() -> Void in
        println("death")
    })
```

Very big thanks to everybody for contributions for a solution!

Comment: I needed the `SKAction.repeatAction( stuff, count: 1)` to work! thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In Swift you can use this extension:

```
extension SKNode
{
    func runAction( action: SKAction!, withKey: String!, optionalCompletion: dispatch_block_t? )
    {
        if let completion = optionalCompletion
        {
            let completionAction = SKAction.runBlock( completion )
            let compositeAction = SKAction.sequence([ action, completionAction ])
            runAction( compositeAction, withKey: withKey )
        }
        else
        {
            runAction( action, withKey: withKey )
        }
    }
}
```

Use for example as:

```
myShip.runAction(move,withKey:"swipeMove",optionalCompletion: {
  //Here action is ended..do whatever you want
}
```

### Swift 3:

```
extension SKNode
{
    func run(action: SKAction!, withKey: String!, optionalCompletion:((Void) -> Void)?) {
        if let completion = optionalCompletion
        {
            let completionAction = SKAction.run(completion)
            let compositeAction = SKAction.sequence([ action, completionAction ])
            run(compositeAction, withKey: withKey )
        }
        else
        {
            run( action, withKey: withKey )
        }
    }

    func actionForKeyIsRunning(key: String) -> Bool {
            return self.action(forKey: key) != nil ? true : false
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
myShip.runAction(action: move, withKey:"swipeMove", optionalCompletion: {
       //Here action is ended..do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: I apologise for two very stupid questions: Why do you assign a `withKey: String!` to this first action?

Comment: What does the second function do: `func actionForKeyIsRunning(key: String) -> Bool {
            return self.action(forKey: key) != nil ? true : false
    }`

Comment: @Confused It simply check if an action is currently in running. It is useful do for example : if !sprite.actionForKeyIsRunning("rotate") { // do rotation) } to avoid rotation override

Comment: argh, this is pretty cool. So, let me see if I have this right??? You can start the action, as per your example, and later check if it's running, like this? `if myShip.actionForKeyIsRunning("swipeMove"){myShip.removeActionForKey("swipeMove")}`

Comment: Yes, it could be used also to remove if you want as you write, of course.

Comment: Completion handlers are horribly under-documented by Apple. They seem like one of the more Swifty things in SpriteKit, too.

Comment: Yes I know. Completion handlers should tell you when a task has been completed. In this case , you last action is a "interruption of service" because you remove an action when it is in run

Comment: Sorry I've seen just only your first comment, the answer for you comment is: because you can identify an action with the key.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano, use `@inline(__always)` to get better performance on your `actionForKeyIsRunning` method.  Inlining a function will reduce overhead that come with functions like pushing and popping to the stack at the cost of a larger binary size.  Since your method is tiny, you will barely notice the increase in size, but you will see an increase in performance if you did a test on it.