# swift: detect which skaction stopped in group

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skaction

i have a node bear that has two skactions on it (in a group). Action bearmove is on a loop, while moveUp is not, moveUP should only happen once.

```
let moveUp=SKAction.moveTo(y:50,duration:1.0)
let bearAnimate=[SKTexture(imageNamed:"image1"),SKTexture(imageNamed:"image2"),SKTexture(imageNamed:"image3"),SKTexture(imageNamed:"image2")]

let bearmove=SKAction.animate(with: bearAnimate,timePerFrame:0.3)
let bearRep=SKAction.repeatForever(bearmove)

 let bearRun = SKAction.group([moveUp, bearRep])
 bear.run(bearRun)
```

I want to know when moveUp completed/ stoped running. I tried:

```
if !bear.hasActions(){
   print("stoped moving")
}
```

but since bearAnimate is on a loop and never stops. This line of code never gets read. Any ideas how to detect one of the actions in a group?

Comment: here is a way to use extensions and keys to know when Actions finish, and then do something: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37722911/2109038. This is more complex than @Mark Brownsword's very elegant and simple technique.

Comment: @Confused that will not help Cindy Smith,  What you provided was a completion handler for when a node is running an action with a key,  Cindy needs to know when an individual action as a part of a group of actions is done.

Comment: Would a completion handler on an action within a group get called? @Knight0fDragon

Comment: @Confused Actions do not have completion handlers, so no

Comment: Then what's the term for this: `func run(action:SKAction,completion:()->())` if it's not called a completion handler? @Knight0fDragon

Comment: @Confused That is on an `SKNode`, not an `SKAction`,  if you read the original question again, you will see the OP tried using that, but failed due to an action in a group having an infinite loop.  Infinite loop means action can never end

Comment: If, for example:  `moveup = run(action:SkAction, completion:() ->())`, and is the first in a group, why wouldn't the completion of `moveup` get called when the SKAction completed, regardless of what the other actions in the group are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create another action to handle what happens after moving, then run these actions as a sequence.

```
let afterMoveHandler = SKAction.runBlock({
    // Your code here
})

let moveSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveUp, afterMoveHandler])
let bearRun = SKAction.group([moveSequence, bearRep])
```

If you want an extension of SKAction to do what you are looking for, consider the following:
(Code is Swift 3)

```
extension SKAction
{
    static func run(action:SKAction,completion:()->()) -> SKAction
    {
       return SKAction.sequence([action, SKAction.run(completion)]
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let moveUpEvent = SKAction.run(action:moveUp){/*do something here*/}
let bearRun = SKAction.group([moveUpEvent , bearRep])
```

Comment: Hope you do not mind, I added an extension off of your answer

Comment: Thanks! this really helped!