# How to wait until SKAction.repeatForever completes the animation sequence in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have an animation running with `SKAction.repeatForever` animation loop, which runs an animation all over again for indefinite amount of time.

```
node.run(SKAction.repeatForever(
    SKAction.animate(with: animationFrames,
                     timePerFrame: timePerFrame,
                     resize: true,
                     restore: true)))
```

I have a user-triggered (with a touch) animation that I want to fire *after* the currently animated loop finishes. How can I catch when the current loop of `SKAction.animate` finishes and then stop, remove and replace the animation with a second one?

```
|--Loop1--|--Loop2--|--Loop3--|--...
                | user trigger here
                    | wait until Loop2 finishes and then replace the animation
```

Pseudo code of what kind of functionality I'm looking for:

```
... somewhere else ... {
    animatedNode.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(...)))
}

func onTouch() {
    foreverRunningAnimation.waitUntilLoopFinishes() {
        animatedNode.removeAllActions()
        animatedNode.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(< second animation>)))
    }
}
```

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627613/skaction-completion-handlers-usage-in-swift

Comment: what?  that makes no sense.  You want to place a "random" delay after an animation phase ends?  Why?  That would make your repeat forever action look silly if the animation is pausing for a random duration

Comment: You can run skaction.sequence as your repeat forever animation

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Let me update my question.

Comment: You dont want repeat forever then, you want a state machine

Comment: Yes. Please answer with code. :)